# jquery column values on click

Tags: jquery

I have a table with 5 columns,,when I click on first column on the row i need to get the all column row values using jquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like your answer in an array:

```
$('table#mytable td:first-child').click( function(){
    var resultArray = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').map( function(){
        return $(this).text();
    });
    // Do something with resultArray
    // resultArray is a jQuery object
    // resultArray.get() is a plain array. get() can be chained above.
});
```

Comment: Change the first instance of `});` to `}).get();` to return an array instead of a jQuery object.

Comment: Just a slight modification, I would add: $("#yourtable").find("td:first-child") instead of globally selecting any $('td:first-child').

Comment: @Jeff: Agreed. I was keeping it simple, but of course you're right that being more specific is better. I'll edit (and modify the selector rather than add the find()).

Comment: @Greg: Yes, good point. I edited the answer (in comments clarifying the two options). In my experience the native array is almost always what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("td:first-child").click(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find("td").each(function(){
    alert(this.innerHTML);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("td").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find("td").each(function(){
    alert(this + " is one entry of your current row");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what is actually IN the table a bit.

```
var mystuff = $("td").click().parent('tr').children('td').text();
var mystuff = $("td").click().parent('tr').children('td').innerHtml();
```

accessing them:

```
mystuff.each(function()
{
 //do stuff
};
mystuff.eq(2) // do stuff with second one
```