# How to get the Particular column value using jquery

Tags: jquery

I used this code to get the particular column value using jquery..

```
$("#Grid td:first-child").click(function() {
                var resultArray = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').text();
                   alert(resultArray);
            });
```

How do I get the particular column value? That is, I need grid 4th and 5th column value?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019938/how-to-get-the-jquery-grid-entire-row-values-on-click/3020032#3020032

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015598/jquery-column-values-on-click/3015687

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **[`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** selector:

```
$("#Grid td:first-child").click(function() {
   var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text(); // for third column
   alert(value);

   var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3)').text(); // for fourth column
   alert(value);
});
```

That will alert value of 3rd and 4rth TD/column when first td of element with id `Grid` (`td:first-child`) is clicked.

If however, you want an array of values of TDs, use the **[`map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)** and **[`get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)** methods like this:

```
$("#Grid td:first-child").click(function() {
   var value_array = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').map(function(){
     return $(this).text();
   }).get();
});
```

Now `value_array` will contains text for found TDs eg:

```
value_array[0] // first
value_array[1] // second
value_array[2] // third
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Grid td:first-child').click( function(){
    var resultArray = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').map( function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    alert(resultArray[2]); // third
    alert(resultArray[3]); // fourth..

});
```

or

```
$('#Grid td:first-child').click( function(){
    var resultArray = $(this).closest('tr')
        //     third     fourth 
        .find('td:eq(2), td:eq(3)').map( function(){
             return $(this).text();
        }).get();

    alert(resultArray[0]); 
    alert(resultArray[1]); 

});
```